# How to update value in a nested json when you know the key?

Tags: javascript, json

I have a nested json object, something like this:

```
{
  "fontweight": {
    "primary": {
      "weight1": {
        "value": "Regular",
        "type": "fontWeights"
      },
      "weight2": {
        "value": "SemiBold",
        "type": "fontWeights"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

Now, I get a key and value, like this:

```
{
    key: "fontweight.primary.weight1.value",
    value: "Bold"
}
```

I need to update the value for the key in my nested json. How can I do so?

Comment: [property-expr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/property-expr) is a micro library that handles more edge cases than your custom code. Use it, or just copy and paste from its source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The structure can be updated in 4 relatively simple steps.

1. Split `"fontweight.primary.weight1.value"` in an array of keys.

   ```
   const keys = update.key.split(".");
   ```
2. Store the final key `"value"` separately. The reason we do this is because the other keys are used to access a value, not to assign it. The final key is used for value assignment.

   ```
   const finalKey = keys.pop();
   ```
3. Navigate to the node/object that needs its attribute changed using the `keys` array. This can be done using [`reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

   ```
   const node = keys.reduce((node, key) => node[key], structure);
   ```

   If you're not familiar with `reduce()` and have trouble understanding the line above. It could also be written as:

   ```
   let node = structure;
   for (const key of keys) node = node[key];
   ```
4. Update the value of the node/object using the final key.

   ```
   node[finalKey] = update.value;
   ```

```js
const structure = {
  "fontweight": {
    "primary": {
      "weight1": {
        "value": "Regular",
        "type": "fontWeights"
      },
      "weight2": {
        "value": "SemiBold",
        "type": "fontWeights"
      }
    },
  }
};

const update = {
  key: "fontweight.primary.weight1.value",
  value: "Bold"
};

const keys     = update.key.split(".");
const finalKey = keys.pop();
const node     = keys.reduce((node, key) => node[key], structure);
node[finalKey] = update.value;

console.log(structure);
```

---

If the key can target a non-existing path you might want to change step 3. Replace `node[key]` in either the `reduce()` callback or `for...of` body with `node[key] ??= {}`. This will try to access `key` on `node`, if its value is nullish (`null` or `undefined`) then `{}` is assigned and returned (see [`??=`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)).

```js
const structure = {};
const update    = { key: "non.existing.key", value: "Hello World!" };

const keys     = update.key.split(".");
const finalKey = keys.pop();
const node     = keys.reduce((node, key) => node[key] ??= {}, structure);
node[finalKey] = update.value;

console.log(structure);
```

Answer (score 2):

## No Lodash required

Assuming the nested JSON doesn't contain the array, you can update JSON value by defining `updateValue` function which takes parameters `data` and an object as `{key:'....',value:'...'}`. That function can be used to copy existing JSON to do some iteration for updating the target key with a new value like this:

```js
let data = {
  "fontweight": {
    "primary": {
      "weight1": {
        "value": "Regular",
        "type": "fontWeights"
      },
      "weight2": {
        "value": "SemiBold",
        "type": "fontWeights"
      }
    },
  }
};

let updateValue = (data, obj) => {
  let key = obj.key.split('.');
  let newValue = obj.value;
  let targetObj = data;
  while(key.length > 1) {
    targetObj = targetObj[key[0]]
    key.shift();
  }
  targetObj[key[0]] = newValue;
  return data;
}

data = updateValue(data, 
  {
    key: "fontweight.primary.weight1.value",
    value: "Bold"
  }
);
console.log(data);
```